# How can I test if a list of files exist?

Tags: command-line, file, shell

I have a file that lists filenames, each on it's own line, and I want to test if each exists in a particular directory. For example, some sample lines of the file might be

```
mshta.dll
foobar.dll
somethingelse.dll
```

The directory I'm interested in is `X:\Windows\System32\`, so I want to see if the following files exist:

```
X:\Windows\System32\mshta.dll
X:\Windows\System32\foobar.dll
X:\Windows\System32\somethingelse.dll
```

How can I do this using the Windows command prompt? Also (out of curiosity) how would I do this using bash or another Unix shell?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In cmd.exe, the **FOR /F %***variable* **IN (** *filename* **) DO** *command* should give you what you want. This reads the contents of *filename* (and they could be more than one filenames) one line at a time, placing the line in %variable (more or less; do a HELP FOR in a command prompt). If no one else supplies a command script, I will attempt.

EDIT: my attempt for a cmd.exe script that does the requested:

```
@echo off
rem first arg is the file containing filenames
rem second arg is the target directory

FOR /F %%f IN (%1) DO IF EXIST %2\%%f ECHO %%f exists in %2
```

Note, the script above *must* be a script; a FOR loop in a .cmd or .bat file, for some strange reason, must have double percent-signs before its variable.

Now, for a script that works with bash|ash|dash|sh|ksh :

```
filename="${1:-please specify filename containing filenames}"
directory="${2:-please specify directory to check}
for fn in `cat "$filename"`
do
    [ -f "$directory"/"$fn" ] && echo "$fn" exists in "$directory"
done
```

Comment: If you replace && by || you can check fo files that do NOT exist.

But you solution will probably not work for filenames with blanks.

Comment: @karsten You are correct about filenames-with-spaces. One can mitigate that in POSIX shell by changing the IFS variable to tab + nl or maybe just plain nl, but I don't know how one could handle that on Windows.

Answer (score 10):

Bash:

```
while read f; do 
    [ -f "$f" ] && echo "$f" exists
done < file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f %i in (files.txt) do @if exist "%i" (@echo Present: %i) else (@echo Missing: %i)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Windows:

```batch
type file.txt >NUL 2>NUL
if ERRORLEVEL 1 then echo "file doesn't exist"
```

(This may not be the best way to do it; it is a way I know of; see also https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080926-00/?p=20743)

In Bash:

```bash
if ( test -e file.txt ); then echo "file exists"; fi
```

Comment: His file.txt contains filenames, it's not the file he's checking for.

Answer (score 1):

Please note, however, that using the default file systems under both Win32 and *nix there is no way to guarantee the atomicity of the operation, i.e. if you check for the existence of files A, B, and C, some other process or thread might have deleted file A after you passed it and while you were looking for B and C.

File systems such as [Transactional NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Transactional_NTFS&oldid=233375400) can overcome this limitation.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add one small comment to most of the above solutions.  They are not actually testing if a particular file exists or not.  They are checking to see if the file exists and you have access to it.  It's entirely possible for a file to exist in a directory you do not have permission to in which case you won't be able to view the file even though it exists.

Comment: What you say is technically correct; practically, though, it's irrelevant. If I don't have the permissions to read/scan a directory and therefore can't reach a file in it to test its existence, what's the difference to it not existing (for me)?